Get the navbar start/end margins left AND right to be close to the edge using bootstrap5
If I remove ms-2 it shifts right, put back in, and it shifts left.
I have tried various options but I can't seem to get my head around how this works, and the order that needs to be in. I find bootstrap complicated in my brain right now...
(I updated the html bit, and put the nav inside the html section (it was a late night rush job, but still proved th point ok))


    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark navbar-dark py-0  sticky-top">
        <div class="container ps-2 ms-2 pe-2 me-2">
            <a href="/" style="color: #9a9d9e">
                <img alt="tz" src="{% static 'main/img/favicon.ico' %}"
                width="33" height="33" class="navbar-brand">
                TrapEEzEE
             </a>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MagneticMovieMatcher</a> -->
    
            <button 
                class="navbar-toggler" 
                type="button" 
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                data-bs-target="#navmenu"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
     
    
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#More" class="nav-link">More</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">col-sm-8</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    </div>
    </body>




When you add a margin start value ms-2, it overrides the default container style of margin-left: auto, which pushes the container to the right. You can see this in action by using the Developer Tools on your browser - disable your ms-2 style and you'll see the margin-left value become active.

But why can't I have BOTH an ms-2 and me-2, so that the start AND the end are both 2 from left and right.  If I add ms-2, it pulls the RH side over to the left a bit.  I'm trying to keep the contents (margins) of the nav equal on the left AND right sides... but it seems to be exclusive left OR right, not BOTH??

You have your nav content inside a container class, not a container-fluid class. Containers have a max-width of 100%, 540px, 720px, 960px, 1140px, or 1320px, depending on the screen size. Fluid containers have a width of 100% and a default padding of 12 pixels. If you want to have your nav content closer or further from the ends, you can override the 12 pixels with the padding classes. One other note – you had a working code snippet, but when you edited your question, you deleted the snippet. Having a working code snippet makes it easier for people to respond to your question.

Very helpful, thank you very much!   I'm not sure exactly what you mean about the code snippet is gone, because when I look I still see the new one that I put up. Are you saying that I didn't? Is there something I need to do to make it show up?

why is your <nav> is out of <html>?
but any way, having ms-2 and me-2 at the same time works for me but if it isn't works for you try mx-2 instead (it means having just horizontal margin 2)

So both ms-2 and me-2 together, and also the mx-2 doesn't seem to work.  The only way I can get the end to go proper, is to remove the ms-2.  Is there some kind of fluid I should be using instead?

I think you want the nav be at the center right? if it is delete both margins
